# run python script with an ini file

Tags: python, ini

i'd like to run a python script with different ini files

I put some variable's in an ini.py and than i would like to run my program.py with this inifile.

I tried something like:

in batch-> program.py ini

```
sys.argv[1]
from sys.argv[1] import *
```

and

```
eval('from '+sys.argv[1]+' import *')
```

but this doesn't work.

now I wrote:

```
import sys
f = open('outp.py','w')
f.write("from "+sys.argv[1]+" import *\n")
f.write("print x\n")
with open('program.py', 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()
f.write(content)
f.close()

execfile( "outp.py")
```

basicly rewriting my program file with an extra import statment....
there is an easier way i hope?! (not neccesarely in batch)
thx

Answer (score 3):

For parsing INI files, you can use the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) standard library module in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__import__` function.

```
my_module=__import__('os')  #basically the same as `import os as my_module`
```

Of course, you can't do `from blah import *` with this, but many people would argue that you shouldn't use that idiom in production code anyway.

However, if you just want to set a few variables, you should instead consider a commandline parsing utility, or a config file parser (`configparser`, `argparse` and `optparse` all come to mind -- all in the standard library) as this will prevent users from running untrusted code.